# Is there a more efficient way to filter through a collection with computed properties?

Tags: ember.js

In short, I am creating a table that is sortable and is filterable by whether the item is *new*, *updated* or needs to be *deleted*. The `FilteredParts` property needs to observe both the `query`, `sortBy` and `model.@each.isDirty` in order to ensure the table is up to date. Changing filters and sorting are quick however if I want to update any model in the collection it very slow. Is there a way to use `model.@each.isDirty` or something similar so that it is not so taxing?

**Here is my controller:**

```
App.VendorPartsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(App.PartTableMixin,{
    queryParams: ['query','sortBy'],
    query: "all",
    hasChanges: function(){
        if(this.get('filteredParts').isAny('isDirty',true))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }.property('filteredParts.@each.isDirty'),
    hasNew: function() {
        if(this.get('filteredParts').isAny('isNew',true))
        {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }.property('filteredParts.@each.isNew'),
    hasUpdated: function() {
        var parts = this.get('filteredParts');
       return parts.any(function(part){
            return part.get('isDirty') && !(part.get('isNew')) && !(part.get('deletable'));
        });
    }.property('filteredParts.@each.isDirty'),
    hasDeleted: function() {
        if(this.get('filteredParts').isAny('deletable',true))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }.property('filteredParts.@each.deletable'),
    filteredParts: function(){
        var parts = this.get('model');
        var query = this.get('query');
        var sortBy = this.get('sortBy');
        switch(query){
            case "new":
                return parts.filterProperty('isNew',true).sortBy(sortBy);
            break;
            case "updated":
                return parts.filter(function(part){
                    return part.get('isDirty') && !(part.get('isNew')) && !(part.get('deletable'));
                }).sortBy(sortBy);
            break;
            case "deleted":
                return parts.filterProperty('deletable',true).sortBy(sortBy);
            break;
            case "all":
                return parts.sortBy(sortBy);
            break;
        }

    }.property('query','sortBy','model.@each.isDirty'),
    actions: {
        undoAll: function() {
            this.get('model').forEach(function(part){
                part.rollback();
            })
            this.transitionToRoute('vendor.parts');
        }
    }
})
```

Here is a mixin that I will probably add back into the controller:

```
App.PartTableMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({

    sortAscending: false,
    sortBy: 'vendor_part_number',

    outOfParts: function()
    {
        if(this.get('filteredParts').length < 1)
        {
            return true;
        }else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }.property('filteredParts.length'),
    actions: {
        trash: function(model){
            if(model.get('isNew'))
            {
                model.rollback();
            }
            else
            {
                model.set('deletable',true);
            }
        },
        undo: function(model) {
            model.rollback();
        }
    }
});
```